# XMPP ASMACK VCARD

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, smack, vcf-vcard

I am not able to get the vcard information.

i have tried both methods,

```
VCard card = new VCard();
card.load(connection);
Log.i("VCARD", card.getFirstName());
```

During this i got that timeout error.....

Plus also have tried this.... before making a connection.

```
configure(ProviderManager.getInstance());

public void configure(ProviderManager pm) {
    pm.addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());
}

final IQ iq = new IQ() {
public String getChildElementXML() {
return "<iq from='test@xx.xx.xx.xx' id='v1' 
type='get'><vCard xmlns='vcard-temp'/>    
</iq>";
 }
};

iq.setType(IQ.Type.GET);
connection.sendPacket(iq);
connection.addPacketListener(new MyPacketListener(),new   PacketTypeFilter(IQ.class));
```

Please guide me how to get VCARD Information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On either of those requests, you'll need to set a `to` address.  Right now, these are going to your server, which likely doesn't implement [XEP-0054](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html).